# Proving $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+nb} \notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ , i want to show that:

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+nb} \notin \mathbb{N}$$

but i can't,i think we should consider the set {$a,a+b,...,a+bn$} and use chebyshev's theorem but i dont know how shoud i use that??!!are there any one help me??

for example in special case, i got $b=1,$ so each number of  {$a,a+1,...,a+n$} is of the form $2^{r}m$ which $b$ is odd and $r>-1$ and we can discuss about $r$.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: A  general resul can be found here: http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_34_from29to31.pdf

Comment: Prove that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}$$ can not be a whole number

Comment: @Moti no i did not.

Comment: OK, so I suggest that now that Moti has given you two hints, you follow those (the second one first) and include the results of your efforts in your question. (You can click on "edit" beneath the question to do this.) Then we can help you along further. By the way, somewhere in your work you're going to need to use the "gcd" thing that's an assumption. Otherwise, for instance, $a = 2, b = 0$ would be a counterexample to Moti's second suggestion

Comment: A statement $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+nb} \neq p $ for all $p\in  \mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to the statement $p\cdot \prod_{1\leq k\leq n}(a+kb)-\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\prod_{\substack{0\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i }}(a+kb)\neq 0$ for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MathOverview do you think from this way we can recive to answer?! i don't

Comment: @RobertZ Fantastic reference! Very general result, and proven by elementary means.

Answer (score 1):

What I write next is not really a response but a strategic one to tackle the problem. A statement $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a+nb} \neq p $ for all $p\in  \mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to the statement 
$$
p\cdot \prod_{1\leq k\leq n}(a+kb)-
\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\prod_{\substack{0\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i }}(a+kb)\neq 0
$$ 
for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$.So it is enough to prove that the equation 
$$
x\cdot \prod_{1\leq k\leq n}(a+kb)-
\sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\prod_{\substack{0\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i }}(a+kb)= 0
$$
has no integer roots for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention , i think this way is hard!!